# custom 404 error page issue

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, seo

i have facing custom 404 page issue 
my directory are follows

1. index.php
2. 404.php

my htaccess code is ..

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([0-9])/ index.php?page=$1

#DirectoryIndex practice.php

IndexIgnore *.gif *.jpg *.png *.css

ErrorDocument 404 practice.php
```

problem is that 404.php page show when url wrong entered but not shown page content
see images

[image]

404 page content is :

```
<h1 align='center'>404 - Page Not Found </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many browsers require custom 404 pages to be at least 512 bytes in size.
If the custom 404 page is not that big of a file, then the browser just shows its default 404 page.

Answer: Put more stuff on your custom 404 page.
Also, fix the ErrorDocument line: `ErrorDocument 404 404.php`

Comment: can u describe completly please